# PHP Insert Into not working

Tags: php, mysql, insert

This code worked for me before, but now, it's not inserting the data into my DB. When I execute it, it receives a message ($mensaje), then connects with the DB and then tries to insert the data, but it can't do it.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pass', 'mydb');
    if(mysqli_connect_errno($conn))
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Error en la conexión');</script>";  
    }

    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Conectado a la base de datos');</script>";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO conversacion (mensaje, idUsuario, leido) VALUES ('$mensaje', NULL, FALSE)";
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Datos introducidos correctamente');</script>";
        }

        else
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Error en la introduccion de datos');</script>";
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
```

Comment: What does it do? Do you get an error or does the insert just not happen?

Comment: It executes the else "echo" (an error code) and does not execute the insert, so I assume that the result of the query is FALSE.

Comment: Change your code so you can see what error the database is returning

Comment: Have you tried to execute your sql query on a mysqli client to see what result you get?

Comment: You're basically not showing any system error message while it could help you by finding the root cause of your problem. As a side remark, by not using prepared statements, your code is prone to SQL injections. And if you don't sanitize your inputs before inserting it in the database, you might also open to XSS attacks...

Comment: "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`synapsis`.`conversacion`, CONSTRAINT `conversacion_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idUsuario`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`idUsuario`))"

This is the error it returns me, but the same query worked before...

Comment: It's a problem with the data you inserting. The "idUsuario" in your insert query does not exist in the "usuarios" table. Since you are trying to pass NULL for the idUsuario, have you checked whether the table allows NULL values? Otherwise it's being converted to 0, which is not a valid id.

Comment: Now it works! There was only one registered 'idUsuario' in the parent table, and, because I was using an auto-increment and NULL, the 'idUsuario' was never the same as the parent table.

Answer (score 0):

since you have made entire sql in string you need to use like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO conversacion (mensaje, idUsuario, leido) VALUES ('$mensaje', 'NULL', 'FALSE')";
```

if you will try to make it something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO play (id, type, periodId) VALUES ('$mensaje',".NULL.",". FALSE.")";
```

then it will **end up** this:

```
INSERT INTO play (id, type, periodId) VALUES ('10',,) // here $mensaje=10 an example a **wrong sql**
```

so better try like this:

```
$mensaje=10;$n=NULL;$flag=true;// here $flag=false will give '' in the sql.
  $sql = "INSERT INTO play (id, type, periodId) VALUES ('$mensaje','$n','$flag')";
```

this will **produce** something like this:

```
INSERT INTO play (id, type, periodId) VALUES ('10','','1')
```

Comment: Actually it's not problem of the query, it's just that I'm doing something wrong with the DB, since is returning me an error of foreign keys and constraints, but I don't know why

Comment: for foreign key a record with the key should be available in the parent table.and also see if you have put some constraint on idUsuario.